# How do you write a regal name with both regnal number and nickname?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, languages

I know this goes beyond the scope of fantasy, but I'm specifically interested in Game of Thrones. I've been compiling a spreadsheet of every named character within Game of Thrones, and am not sure how to deal with nicknames and regnal numbers. For example, would I write the name of Aegon Targaryen, fourth of his name, known as "the Unworthy", as:

> Aegon IV "the Unworthy" Targaryen

or

> Aegon "the Unworthy" IV Targaryen

Or some other method entirely? Perhaps it seems strange to include nicknames, but given just how prolific ASOIAF's character list is - particularly House Targaryen - I figured it was a useful method of differentiation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Database in third normal form, perhaps. But I'm not sure you asked in the right place. This platform is dedicated to unrealistic, fantastic problems/questions. Your question on the other hand is very worldly and reasonable.

Comment: I shan't post this on ELU because Richard's answer was satisfactory - unless someone really wants to close the question.

Comment: @Einer, I could use a normalised database but it seems excessive. A flat-file will meet my needs and still be perfectly readable.

Comment: Yeah, might be kind of an overkill ;-). Anyway: Welcome to scifi.stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you :)! I suppose I could split the character field into regnal number, title, cognomen, forename and house name, but I suppose it would waste space given that there are a great many characters who only have a forename.

Comment: @Einer This site is not dedicated solely to unrealistic and/or fantastical problems and questions. [Story Identification](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) and [Suggested Order](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) questions are just two examples that are neither unrealistic or fantastic. I'd say this question is well within the realm of on-topic for this site, due to the source.

Comment: @Xantec True. What I meant to say was: This site is about fiction. And questions like "Should I copy my Star-Trek collection from VHS to DVD" is somewhat fiction-related, but it's answer applies to cat-videos too and hence it's would be misplaced here. It would be no fiction-question. And I feel this one is neither. Viewing Order and Story Identification on the other hand are question concerning only fiction.

Comment: I would give this question a pass, but don't let it happen again :-).

Comment: Okay :). I've got what I came for, anyway.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure this would be on-topic for English Language and Usage because their [FAQ specifically says questions about naming are off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There was a [meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4617) about the naming of people and families within the English language, the end result of which was to move such questions to [Genealogy.SE](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/). This may be a further sub-class, however, since it is about writing names in English, not actually naming things.

Comment: I stand corrected on the correction. What I thought a typo was actually a correctly spelled and properly applied word. My vocabulary has increased accordingly.

Comment: Worry not, @Morgan, I only learned the term `regnal number` recently, and I think it was from this website :').

Comment: @Dacio, do you consider the question on topic for scifi?

Comment: To make it unquestionably on-topic for SF&F.SE, it could say 'Does George R.R. Martin ever reference full monarch names combined with regnal numbers and cognomen? *(Aside: could we say those were the rulers'* [monarch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moniker)- *ers?)* If so, how does he write it? If not, what are some examples where he uses a name and a number in close proximity?' But FWIW, I +1'ed you a long time ago.

Comment: Awh :). Okay, well I'm content with the question as is if everyone else is. And SF&F.SE? Is that the standard abbreviation? (seems so much more obfuscated than scifi!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pretty much all real-world cases, the use of the [cognomen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchs_by_nickname) would supersede the need to use the formal title. Bluntly, if a monarch is (in)famous enough to merit a nickname, then you don't need the numbers to know which one you're talking about.

In writing, you'd almost certainly go with the first example;

- **Ivan IV "The Terrible" of Russia**,

or possibly even

- "Ivan IV Vasilyevich, ***commonly known as "Ivan the Terrible"***.

Comment: The second option seems the most natural to me: Aegon IV Targaryen, also known as "Aegon the Unworthy".

Comment: That's good to know. However, I think I'll go with `Ivan IV "The Terrible" Vasilyevich`, because I'm using a single name field and don't want to overcrowd it, and now that I think about it, it makes it easier to search.